# Loading screen/div for images loaded AFTER page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loading

I've created a loading screen with a div that fades out after the page loads, however I have a gallery that loads from another html page once the user clicks a link (using Jquery). I need to create another loading screen that appears when the button is pressed.

Current Jquery:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $("#preloader").fadeOut(300);
});

$('#header-amsterdam').click(function() {
    $("#gallery_amsterdam").load("amsterdamgallery.html");{);
```

Current CSS:

```
#preloader {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(255,165,0,1.00);
z-index: 2000;
```

}

HTML loaded from seperate document:

```
<div class="image">
    <ul class="image_holder">
        <li><a class="image1 image_select" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM1.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM2.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM3.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM4.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM5.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM6.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM7.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM8.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM9.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM10.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM11.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM12.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM13.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM14.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM15.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM16.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM17.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM18.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM19.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        <li><a class="image1" href="#"><img src="images/AM/AM20.jpg" width="100%" height="auto"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show the loading overlay in the `click` event handler, hide it again in the callback of the `load()`

Comment: I tried this, the loader fades out once the div has been loaded but the images within are still loading.